# Order_items not expiring after setting background checks in order_cleaner.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller

I'm building a store in rails. A store has orders, order_items, users..

Right now when customer adds order_item to a cart, order with unique id is created automatically, and order_items are saved under order_items model. There is also validation saying that only 3 order_items are allowed in one order.

If possible, I would like to remove those order_items that are saved to a model after 5 minutes. 5 minutes counter should start after saving all 3 order_items.

What I did:

I added order_cleaner. to config/initializers/order_cleaner.rb in order to do background process and periodically check the database and remove those saved order_items..

Here is how it looks:

```
Thread.new do
  while true
    # Get all orders with at least 3 order_items
    orders = Orders.joins(:order_items).group('orders.id').having('count(order_id) >= 3')
    orders.each do |o|
      # Delete associated order_item if it's older than 5 minutes
      o.order_items.each {|oi| oi.destroy! if oi.updated_at < 5.minutes.ago }
    end
    sleep 1.minute
  end
end
```

I check back after 5 minutes after adding 3 order_items and all order_items are still present. They haven't been removed. What could be the issue and do you have any other solution to achieve this?

Thanks

Relevant code:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_items
  validates_length_of :order_items, maximum: 3 #only 3 order_items are allowed within an order for each user
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal



  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end



end
```

order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
  validates_associated :order
  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :product_present
  validate :order_present


  before_save :finalize

  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def product_present
    if product.nil?
      errors.add(:product, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end


end
```

order_items_controller.rb

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @order = current_order
  @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
  @order.user_id = current_user.id
  @order.save
  session[:order_id] = @order.id


  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { flash[:notice] = "ORDER HAS BEEN CREATED." } 
  end
end



  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end



  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end


private

  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id, :user_id)

 end
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.decimal  "unit_price",  precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.decimal  "total_price", precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
    t.boolean  "has_ordered"
  end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal  "subtotal",             precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.decimal  "tax",                  precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.decimal  "shipping",             precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.decimal  "total",                precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.integer  "order_status_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "ordered"
    t.date     "first_item_added_at"
    t.date     "first_order_added_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in `Orders.joins` should be `Order.joins`

Also you could use a gem like https://github.com/plashchynski/crono to schedule jobs, in the way of cron for unix.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the `while` in the code for the initializer, I think you're having issues with the database connection not being fully ready when the code runs. You should try to move this to an ActiveJob with a runner like sidekiq and use something like crono to schedule the job.

Comment: you can use `Order.connected?` to check if the connection has been established

Comment: But it's really not that complex task.. I don't know how to use sidekiq and crono..

Comment: `Orders.joins` should be `Order.joins`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116216/discussion-between-neydroid-and-marko-i).